# API4 authorization failure when creating a participant

Tags: civievent, api, participants, authentication

I am currently trying to create a participant on a Drupal form submit, when i do this I get an error saying Authorization failed. I've tried managing the ACLs in Civi with no success, I've also changed the drupal roles to allow anyone to add a participant. I've also tried to set the permissions manually using the code below

```
hook_civicrm_alterAPIPermissions($entity, $action, &$params, &$permissions) {
  $permissions['Participant'] = array(
    'get' => array(
      'access CiviCRM',
      'access CiviEvent',
      'edit all events',
    ),
  );
}
```

but this didn't work either

If anyone has any suggestions it would be a great help, I can supply more information if needed

thanks in advanced!

EDIT:
I found that I needed to allow users access to the backend of civi to get this to work, this is not ideal so I am still looking for workarounds

Comment: `I am currently trying to create a participant on a Drupal form submit` - can you share the code of this part so we can see where the error is being generated?

Comment: Do you have solution im have same problem with permission and api4 ?

Comment: So my current workaround for this was to check the permissions to access all civicrm api which gives the user access to the civicrm backend which isn't ideal, however I think you can do the same stuff with api 3 without having to give the user access to civi